# Mocha test interdependencies?

Tags: javascript, testing, coffeescript, dependencies, mocha.js

Mocha tests appear to run independently and asynchronously.

However, sometimes it makes sense for one test to depend on another test having gone before it, like so:

```coffee
describe 'Authentication flow', ->
   user = email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'passwd'

   it 'registers a user', (done) ->
        register user, (err, res) ->
            return done(err) if err?
            done()

   it 'logs a user in', (done) ->
        login user, (err, res) ->
            return done(err) if err?
            done()
```

Currently I am running these sort of tests within one `it` block inside an `async.waterfall`.

Is there not some way to to chain these together? Without increasingly more indentation like so:

```
    it 'does', (done) ->
            it 'something', (_done) ->
                _done()
                done()
```